# How to move a file from a subdirectory to another subdirectory located outside the first one?

Tags: shell, command-line, directory, filenames

i am at `fickur`the first one and trying to move the inner fickur to digital with only one command line, but cant seem to figure this one out.
[image: photo] 
here is what i have tried so far:

`mv -v fickur/ ./klockor/armbandsur/digital`

results:

`mv: rename fickur/ to ./klockor/armbandsur/digital: No such file or directory`

Comment: Your target directory is missing. Try `mkdir./klockor/armbandsur/digital` and try again

Comment: i have all the directories needed  just as shown in the photo so that isnt the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inside the dir `fickur` (the rectangular one in the drawing), do

```
mv fickur/ ../armbandsur/digital/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concise answer, any idea how i could go about copying `fickur` (the flag shaped one) to `digital` if i am in currently inside `digital` ? i was thinking something like `cp -r ../../fickur/fickur digital` but that doenst seem to work

Comment: `cp -r ../../fickur/fickur .` should work.

Answer (score 0):

When a path doesn't start with `/`, it is relative. A relative path is usually relative to the current working directory (an exception is targets of symlinks that are relative to the parent of the symlink). `.` is an entry in any directory that points to itself.

```
mv -v fickur/ ./klockor/armbandsur/digital
```

is the same as

```
mv -v fickur/ klockor/armbandsur/digital
```

If your current directory is the first `fickur`, there's no `klockor` directory in it, so that can't work. There is no `klockor` directory in the parent of `fickur` either. There would be one in the parent of its parent, but here, you don't need to go that far up if you want to move it to a subdirectory of your parent directory. `armbandsur` is a subdirectory of the parent of `fickur`, so you can just do

```
mv -v fickur ../armbandsur/digital
```

`..` here being the parent directory of the current directory.

Note that if the structure you're describing above includes symlinks, for instance, if `fickur` is not a real directory but a symbolic link, then the `..` in the directory it points to may point to a different directory than `klockor`. Also if the second `fickur` is also a symlink and to a relative path, then when moved to a different location, that link is likely to become broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure how many `../` to do you can always use the full path. With `tab` completion sometimes it is clearer and pretty quick to type. For example (assuming `klockor` is at `/`):

```
mv -v /klockor/flickur/flickur /klockor/armbandsur/digital/
```